# Java Static Factory conversion

Tags: java, concurrency, static-methods, static-factory

On my Client/Server Desktop application. I have this problem of how I should properly code my JDBC class with my Models to ensure all persistence request can support concurrency. `i.e., multiple models want to request update to its persistence counterpart simultaneously [without atmost delay].`

The scenario goes like this. Following the classes located in the server application.

Persitence Package:

```
abstract class AbstractService {
  // other fields
  private final String tName, tId;
  private final String sqlStatement;
  public AbstractService(final String tName, final String tId) {
    this.tName = tName;
    this.tId = tId;
    this.sqlStatement = ""; // SELECT statement
  }
  // java.sql.Connection() createConnection()
  // methods
}
public class T1Service extends AbstractService {
  private final String sqlDMLStatements;
  public T1Service() {
    super("t1", "t1Id");
    this.sqlDMLStatements = ""; // other DML statements
  }      
  // methods having return types of List<E>, Object, Boolean, etc.
  // i.e., public List<E> listAll()
}
```

Communication class [Client class]

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client extends Observable{
  private Socket socket;
  private ObjectInputStream input;
  private ObjectOutputStream output;
  private Object message;
  // Constructor
  // Getters/Setters
  // Other methods like open or close input/output
  private class ReceiverRunnable implements Runnable
    @Override
    public void run() {
       while(running) { // if socket is still open and I/O stream are open/initialized
          try { message = input.readObject(); } 
          catch(Exception e) {}
          finally { setChanged(); notifyObservers(); }  
       } 
    }
  }
}
```

The Main Class [Server class]

```
import java.net.*;
public class Server {
   private List<Client> clientList; // holds all active connections with the server
   private T1Service    t1Service
   private class ConnectionRunnable implements Runnable {
      @Override public void run() {
         while(running) { // serverSocket is open
           Client client = new Client(ServerSocket.accept(), /* other parameters */);
           client.addObserver(new ClientObserver(client));
           clientList.add(client);
         }
      } 
   }
   private class ClientObserver implements Observer {
      private Client client;
      // Constructor
      public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
         // Check the contents of 'message' to determine what to reply
         // i.e., message.equals("Broadcast") {
         // synchronized(clientList) {
         //   for(Client element : clientList) {
         //     element.getOutput().writeObject(replyObject);
         //     element.getOutput()..flush();
         //   }
         // }
         // i.e., message.equals("T1") {
         // synchronized(t1Service) {
         //     client.getOutput().writeObject(t1.findAll());
         //     client.getOutput().flush();
         // }
      } 
   } 
}
```

Since this is a Client/Server applcation, multiple request from the client are simultaneously feed to the server. The server process the request sending the appropriate reply to the approriate client. *Note: All of the objects sent between Client & Server an instance of java.io.Serializable.*

Having this kind of scenario and looking into the block of `Server.ClientServer.update()` we may have a performance issue or I should say a delay in processing the N client(s) request due to `Intrinsic Locks`. But since I have to the rules `concurrency` and `synchronization` to ensure that `Server.T1Service` won't get confused to the queue of N clients request to it. Here's are the questions:

1. According to the Item 1 of [Effective Java - Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) regarding `Static Factory`, would this let me create a new class reference to the methods inside the classes of Persistence package?
2. Would each `Client` element inside `List<Client>` would form a concurrency issue having N client update their `message` field simultaneously triggering the `ClientObsver.update()` wherein the reference object(s) of this Observer is only a single instance in the parent class. *I was avoiding creating multiple instance of T1Service due to memory concerns.*
3. If we are going to go by the contents of Effective Java - Second Edition, how can I convert my persitence class in a way they can be read easily, easily instantiated, and support concurreny?

Comment: to be clear, is there state being modified in the T1Service.update() method? If there is no state being changed in the class when the method is called concurrently, there is no thread safety issue.

Comment: What I've foreseen to be a concurrent issue is when `T1Service.update()` is trigger when 2 or more clients update. I have forgotten to add the information about `List<E extends java.util.Observable>` contains `java.io.Sockets`. What E is it holds the Socket, I/O Streams and most of all `java.lang.Object message` coming from `java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject()`. When `java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject()` receives a new object, `java.util.Observable.setChanged()` and `java.util.Observable.notifyObservers()` are called.

Comment: The level of detail here isn't clear - is that List an argument to the update() method, or a field of the service class? It would be much easier to just show us sample method signatures and class definitions.

Comment: The `List` is a return type of a method in the service class. `List<E>` where `E` is a domain.

Comment: I've updated my question with the details part of the possible concurrent issue / performance issue specifically found on the Server.ClientObserver.update() method.

Comment: I have revised my question in a more consitent manner regarding concurrency and static factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my theory of [Item 1] Static Factory correct?

Yes, you can use a static factory instead of constructors.  Typically this is when you the construction logic is complex and shared between various subtypes to warrant a factory pattern.  Additionally the factory may provide means for dependency injection outside of a DI framework.

> Would it then solve the concurrency issue of the converted static factory global objects?

If you need to synchronize construction, then a static factory works well, just add `synchronized` to the method declaration on your factory methods.  If you need to synchronize methods on the objects themselves then this will not help.

> Is it advisable for me to convert to static factory if where dealing with concurrent access to a global object and where wanted real-time access to the methods of each global object?

As I answered above, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.  For constructor synchronization use a factory.

Comment: The 3rd question may return `List<E>` but since we may not know the number of elements in it. This may cause performance issue, thus, delaying the locking if I would add `synchronized` to each method of the subclass(es).

Comment: What did you mean by `construction logic`? Are you pertaining to the creation of E or List<E>?

Comment: By construction logic I mean code involved in building valid objects including any verification/manipulation of parameters.  Why do you need to lock, what is being modified concurrently?

Comment: I don't necessarily need a lock or to lock for a method in a global object. There may be an scenario where two or more Client update their message object and from the message I will determine what global object and method is to be invoked. What worries me is that when two or more Client send similar request to the server. The server will queue the request to avoid simultaneous request to call the particular method.

Comment: The problem is when two or more `Client` request is queued in order to determine which one will access a method in a global object. What I want to happen is the we would remove the queue in a way when `Client`(s) send the same type of request, the process would also be done simultaneously thus also sending them simultaneously as the reply from the `Server` to the request sent by a `Client`.

Comment: You could iterate through the queue, look for duplicates and serve them in the same request.  I'm still unsure why you need to synchronize though, are they performing operations on the same set of data?

Comment: Yes. Since its a Client/Server application and to optimize performance, whenever there's a need for a Client to broadcast a particular message to all/some of the active Client(s) [or the `List<Client>`] connected to the server, the methods of the global objects is invoked. But this is only for a Client. What if another Client would send a broadcast message to another set of Client from the `List<Client>`.

Comment: I'll be added another set of code snippet to supply my question.

Comment: I have revised my question to clearly understand the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

you may also want to review Actors, for example ones in [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html)

basic idea of actors is avoiding of synchronization at all, using sending events. Akka will guarantee that one actor will never be invoked by two threads in parallel. So you may define actor, which does something with the global variables, and then simply send a message to it.

works like a charm usually :)

Comment: I'm not sure this would be of help. Though I am dealing with N actors where the actors are the Clients in the Client/Server schema. I can't see the relation to my question when you ment _one actor will never be invoked by two thread in parallel_.